# Select query with many to many relationship

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, join, many-to-many

i have thi DB structure

```
CREATE TABLE man (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    name TEXT
);


CREATE TABLE work (
    work_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
);

CREATE TABLE manWork {
    man_id INTEGER,
    work_id INTEGER,
    FOREIGN KEY(man_id) REFERENCES man(id),
    FOREIGN KEY(work_id) REFERENCES work(work_id)
};
```

how will the SELECT query if I want to get a list of all men and for every man also all the jobs associated to that man?

Comment: Note: the ManWork *junction table* needs a primary key (man_id,work_id) since a man cannot do the same work twice; that would be meaningless ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
    m.name
    , w.*
FROM
    man m
         INNER JOIN manWork mw ON m.id = mw.man_id
         INNER JOIN work w ON mw.work_id = w.work_id
```

Wasn't sure from your question but if you want ALL men regardless of if they have a record in the manWork table, then use LEFT JOIN instead of INNER JOIN.

Answer (score 1):

[***`JOIN`***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29) the tables:

```
SELECT
  m.name,
  w.*
FROM manwork mw
INNER JOIN work w ON mw.work_id = w.work_id
INNER JOIN man  m ON mw.man_id  = m.id
```